# CSS Variables Polyfil - IE11 for LitePicker JS

Tags: javascript, datepicker, initialization

I am using a DatePicker js library called LitePicker JS for a project which has been flawless so far. It uses no dependencies and has been easy to style. The only issue is that it does not work in I.E11 due to the litepicker using CSS variables. The documentation on the LitePicker Js library site recommends using an ie11CustomProperties polyfill to make it work but It. I installed the script via npm - tried it, the script does load fine (i can see it in the header using dev tools for IE), the datepicker opens when you click in the form field but the styling is still all broken in I.E11.

From me checking one of the CSS properties using dev tools, this is what is happening:

instead of  `width: 266px;`

the browser is reading it as:

`-ieVar-width: var(--litepickerDayWidth);`

Which is incorrect.

As much as IE11 is ridiculous to need to support these days unfortunately I've been told it needs to work in it. If anyone has any experience with this polyfill could I get some advice on what is going wrong? This is the LitePicker:

https://wakirin.github.io/Litepicker/

and this is the polyfill:

https://github.com/nuxodin/ie11CustomProperties

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Don't forget that you need to include this polyfill first and then Litepicker (as stated in the docs of Litepicker). I'm sure this polyfill works, thanks @Tobias Buschor for this great polyfill.

Answer (score 2):

Hi i am the author of this polyfill.

To make css-variables work, i have to rewrite all the stylesheets.
In IE11 `width:var(...)` fails and is skipped by the css-parser.
Bud `-ieVar-width: var(...)` is not skipped and the polyfill later can read it.

If you can make me a demo on https://jsbin.com/, I can check it out.